# How To Add Nexts.js to Laravel

Tags: laravel, next.js

I want to add next.js framework to Laravel
In preset we have
[php artisan preset react]
But I'm not sure how to do with next.js

How can I add next.js to laravel clean and correct as adding React with preset?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Adding a strong and sophisticated framework such as Next.js to laravel, would be very long long way to code and debug, and IMHO wouldn't be the optimal or feasible solution, specially if we came to ***SSR***

Instead, you can use it as if you are making an SPA in react, which use Laravel as api or use Lumen; and then pass the data to Next.js through ajax, while using Next router.

To do this, there is a routing gotcha you need to make sure you don't fall in its trap, which is server routing and Next routing; you just pass this to Laravel route/web.php

```
Route::fallback(function () {
    return view('your-react-page');
});
```

passing this will make sure that all routes are falling back to this page, if you want any other links to be served by Laravel, just make sure to add them before the fallback.

or if you want to specify a route, you can always use regex.

Comment: So after all is that possible to create app with next js and Laravel or not?

Comment: @DeepSojitra yes, you can using Laravel as backend and NextJs as SPA, the question is about adding NextJs as a preset.